# Calculate performance based on rating table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to bigquery, I have a problem calculating correct rating for user because the rating definition is also depends on year and week.

Consider we have a table of users KPI

| Year | Week | Task | User | KPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 38 | A | John | 5.3 |
| 2023 | 39 | A | Gia | 4.8 |
| 2023 | 39 | B | Gia | 1.1 |
| 2023 | 40 | A | Gia | 5.0 |
| 2023 | 40 | A | John | 5.7 |

and performance table as reference for the rating.

| Year | Week | Task | Base | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 31 | A | 5 | 0.5 |
| 2023 | 31 | B | 1 | 0.1 |
| 2023 | 40 | A | 5.5 | 0.5 |

Case example, if a user doing task A in week 38, we need to evaluate the rating based on the definition of task A week 31. If the user has less than 5.0 KPI, it will have "top" rating, 5.0-5.5 for "average", and kpi above 5.5 for "low" rating.

I tried using a temporary function and nested select, but it returns correlated subquery error.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Please post your query that you have created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
WITH temp_kpi AS (
  SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%Y %W', FORMAT('%i %i', Year, Week)) cut_date
  FROM user_kpi
), temp_performance AS (
  SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%Y %W', FORMAT('%i %i', Year, Week)) cut_date
  FROM performance_lookup
)
SELECT k.* EXCEPT(cut_date),
  CASE 
    WHEN k.KPI < p.Base THEN 'top'
    WHEN k.KPI BETWEEN p.Base AND p.Base + p.Diff THEN 'average'
    WHEN k.KPI > p.Base + p.Diff THEN 'low'
    ELSE 'n/a'
  END AS rating
FROM temp_kpi k
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, LEAD(cut_date, 1, CURRENT_DATE) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Task ORDER BY cut_date) AS next_cut_date
  FROM temp_performance 
) p
ON k.Task = p.Task 
AND k.cut_date >= p.cut_date 
AND k.cut_date < p.next_cut_date
```

with result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple join work?

```
select user_kpi.*,
       case when user_kpi.kpi < pl.base then 'top'
            when user_kpi.kpi between pl.base and pl.base + pl.diff
                 then 'average'
            when user_kpi.kpi > pl.base + pl.diff
                 then 'low'
        end as rating
  from user_kpi
 inner
  join performance_lookup pl
    on user_kpi.year = pl.year
   and user_kpi.week = pl.week
   and uesr_kpi.task = pl.task
```

Comment: The year and week should be less or equal, because the definition might come from previous week.

Comment: @LeleMabur Ah, makes sense. My mistake.